# Using scope operator to access non-static member variables

Tags: c++, scope

It's a fact that you can explicitly access member variables (inside a member function, and not particularly a constructor) using this syntax : `this->member_name` (i.e. to distinguish with a function argument with the same name).

Besides this, I thought that the syntax `ClassName::static_member` was reserved to access static members outside of a class.

Then I was surprised when I realized that the following `set_2()` method was working as one could expect:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int x;
    // The two following methods seem to act similarly:
    void set_1(int x) { this->x = x; }
    void set_2(int x) { A::x = x; }
};

int main ()
{
    A a;

    a.set_1(13);
    std::cout << a.x << std::endl;

    a.set_2(17);
    std::cout << a.x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
13
17
```

Is is a good and valid practice to use the scope operator (`A::x`) in this case? I would personnally prefer it, instead of using the `this->x` syntax.

Comment: IMHO, don't use names that causes conflicts like that and you don't have to use either syntax.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : many people give this advice, but I find it quite more clear for my part to give the same name, especially with a direct assignment (only one name for one task)

Comment: I would decorate one of the names.  I quite like trailing _ as a member variable decorator.  Alternatively, you can use prefix "m_" for the member and/or "a_" for the argument.  The important thing is to pick one style and stick to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `A::x` in this case is valid, but I think `this->x` is more idiomatic and less error-prone (the reader of the code can immediately see that `x` is a member of the class, without thinking what `A` is).

Answer (score 3):

According to the C++ Standard (3.3.7 Class scope)

> 2 The name of a class member shall only be used as follows:
>
> — in the scope of its class (as described above) or a class derived
>   (Clause 10) from its class,
>
> — after the . operator applied to an expression of the type of its
>   class (5.2.5) or a class derived from its class,
>
> — after the -> operator applied to a pointer to an object of its class
>   (5.2.5) or a class derived from its class,
>
> — after the :: scope resolution operator (5.1) applied to the name of
>   its class or a class derived from its class.

For example data members of methods of a derived class can hide data members and/or methods of its base class. To access data members and nethods of the base class you can use the scope resolution operator.

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() {};
    virtual void Hello() const { std::cout << "Base" << std::endl; }
};


struct Derived : Base
{
    virtual void Hello() const 
    { 
        Base::Hello();
        std::cout << "and Derived" << std::endl; 
    }
};

Derived d;

d.Hello();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `A::x`, in your case, still refers to your regular member variable; it just explicitly specifies *which* `x` you mean.  Consider a class that derives from two other classes which have a member of the same name (not that that's very good coding style):

```
struct A { int x; };
struct B { int x; };
struct C : A, B
{
  int foo() const
  {
    // return x;  // ambiguous: which x do you mean?
    return A::x;  // unambiguous
  }
};
```